# Strategy for Mobile App Business Logic Layer

Tags: java, android, ios, rest, windows-phone-8

We are developing a new mobile app and we do need create it on multiple platforms (IOS, Android and Windows Phone).

I'm a software architect with huge background on .NET platform.

We really need to create the most interative and intuitive mobile apps. So, probably I'm going for writing specific native mobile apps and learning new language and new development environments.

The second challenge which I'm dealing with, is that I'm looking for creating a reusable business logic layer, which I could invoke/use the same businessess services from IOS, Android or Iphone.

I was thinking about creating Rest business services to reuse in each native app implementation. In my mind it would be very fast systems cause would exchange only needed data between presentation layer (IOS, Android, Windows Phone) and business services layer. I was thinking about implementing OAuth for security reasons and host it at Amazon Web Services for security, cost ($$) and scalability reasons.

Is that possible? What do you think (and suggest) about it?

Comment: That's a pretty common scenario, your create a REST api and your apps invoke the methods of your API. If you don't need a very interactive APP you could use a different development environment that allows you to only develop one app and export to all platforms.

Comment: Thanks José! What are the security recommendations could you give me for this rest api?

Comment: If you are familiar with oauth2, go for it. I usually use a simple token-based authentication (with or without SSL)... And nothing more in particular, just follow a checklist like the top10 OWASP. (things like hard-to-guess ids, access control, etc)

Comment: If you also need offline syncing which is generally the case in mobile apps, your REST APIs would consist of sync specific APIs rather than directly coupled to views.

Answer (score 1):

You may check to what extend Android and IOS support calls to JavaScript logic within your application. It may be cumbersome to run logic locally in an invisible webview to have javascript as basis for your business logic.
Windows supports JavaScript for both Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8.1 Applications (announced at build conference yesterday).
This would also make it possible to reuse the Javascript code in any web pages you may also have.